# Is cyclic modules $=$ simple modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

Let $A$ be an algebra with identity $1$ and $N$ be a right module of $A$ generated by $n_1 \in N$. That is $N=n_1A$. Is $N$ a simple module? I think that maybe this is not true. Let $N=A$ and suppose that $n_1=1 \in N=A$ is not primitive. Then $N=1.A=A$ is not simple. But I read some books and it is said that $N$ is simple. I am confused. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, not all cyclic modules are simple (think about non-zero principal ideals in $\mathbb Z$, or $\mathbb C[X]$).

Perhaps you are thinking of the converse statement, that all simple modules are cyclic.

Comment: And is the converse true?

Comment: @awllower Yes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_module

Comment: @Potato Thanks. I see the reasoning now.

Answer (score 1):

Let M be a left module over a non-conmutative ring. If M is cyclic and every non-zero element of M is a generator of M then M is simple.